# Parse server notifications for android not logging in GCM and not received on device

Tags: android, parse-platform, push

I'm new to android so please bear with me.

I've tried my very best to configure parse server (on Heroku) to send notifications to my android app and I've (hopefully) appropriately configured AndroidManifest.xml as well (see below).

When I send a notification using parse dashboard it seems to suggest that it has been sent in the Heroku logs (i'm not developing for iOS hence the error on the second line):

**Heroku Logs:**

```
2016-11-16T20:33:29.713489+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/parse/push" host=heartofengland.herokuapp.com request_id=03ac09c2-3209-4d12-a7eb-e2e7f72e2dde fwd="104.238.169.124" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=482
2016-11-16T20:33:29.761488+00:00 app[web.1]: Can not find sender for push type ios, {"where":{},"data":{"alert":"Test message"}}
```

The issue is however nothing logs in GCM nor do i get a notification on my device.

From the numerous guides I have followed, they would all seem to suggest I have configured parse and AndroidManifest.xml correctly - obviously I seem to be missing something (See below).

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

**Parse index.js:**

```
// Example express application adding the parse-server module to expose Parse
// compatible API routes.

var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;

var databaseUri = process.env.DATABASE_URI || process.env.MONGOLAB_URI;

if (!databaseUri) {
  console.log('DATABASE_URI not specified, falling back to localhost.');
}


var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || '',  
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || '', 
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '', 
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || '',  

  push: {
    android: {
        senderId: 'XXXXXXXXXX', //Obscured for security
        apiKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    }
  }
 });


var app = express();

// Serve the Parse API on the /parse URL prefix
var mountPath = process.env.PARSE_MOUNT || '/parse';
app.use(mountPath, api);

// Parse Server plays nicely with the rest of your web routes
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).send('I dream of being a web site.');
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('parse-server-example running on port ' + port + '.');
});
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="uk.co.alexwoodhouse.drawview.drawviewtest">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <permission android:protectionLevel="signature" android:name="${packageName}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="${packageName}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.gcm_sender_id"
            android:value="@string/gcm_sender_id"/>

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="${packageName}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="Heart of England"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".TimeTable"
            android:label="Timetable"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Twitter"
            android:label="Twitter Feed" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Emails"
            android:label="School Email"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you put google-services.json file in your Android app ?

Comment: I do have that file in the /app folder in my project. I did however get the file by signing up to firebase and using the messaging service through that. Would this still work?